# Why is probability that at least one hypothesis out of $k$ being consistent with $m$ training examples $k(1- \epsilon)^m$?

Tags: machine-learning, proofs, probability, computational-learning-theory, statistics

My question is actually related to the addition of probabilities. I am reading on computational learning theory from [Tom Mitchell's machine learning book](http://profsite.um.ac.ir/~monsefi/machine-learning/pdf/Machine-Learning-Tom-Mitchell.pdf).

In chapter 7, when proving the upper bound of probabilities for $\epsilon$ exhausted version space (theorem 7.1), it says that the probability that at least one hypothesis out of the $k$ hypotheses in the hypotheses space $|H|$ being consistent with *m* training examples is at most $k(1- \epsilon)^m$.

I understand that the probability of a hypothesis, $h$, consistent with *m* training examples is $(1-\epsilon)^m$. However, why is it possible to add the probabilities for $k$ hypotheses? And might the probability be greater than 1 in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A$ and $B$ be two events. In general, the probability that either $A$ or $B$ occurs is defined as

$$
P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \text{ and } B)
$$

If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, i.e. they cannot happen at the same time, then $P(A \text{ and } B) = 0$, so the above formula becomes

$$
P(A \text{ or } B) = P(A) + P(B)
$$

If the probability of one **arbitrary** hypothesis being consistent with $m$ training examples is $(1-\epsilon)^m$, then, given the rule above and assuming that only one hypothesis is consistent with $m$ training examples, the probability of **one or more** (i.e. at least one) of the hypotheses being consistent with training examples is the sum of the probabilities, i.e. $k (1-\epsilon)^m$.

This probability can be bigger than one if more than one hypothesis is consistent with $m$ training examples. In that case, you have to take into account the probability that both hypotheses are consistent.

See e.g. notes [General Probability, I: Rules of probability](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/408/408general1.pdf) for more details about the union rule and other rules of probability.

Comment: is $k(1 - \epsilon)^m$ a lower bound on the probability that exactly one hypothesis out of k is consistent ?

Comment: @calveeen It cannot be a lower bound. The probability that one hypothesis out of $k$ is consistent (according to you and your book) is $(1 - \epsilon)^m$, which is smaller than $k(1 - \epsilon)^m$, because $k \geq 1$.